# Установка Idea на Ubuntu 14

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ubuntu

Сегодня мой первый день с Ubuntu. Поиском выловил, как поставить Open JDK, установку Oracle JDK не осилил, может, потом. Пытаюсь поставить Idea, следуя их вики - [link text](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Installing_and_running_IntelliJ_IDEA_on_Ubuntu). При попытке запуска idea.sh получаю сообщение об ошибке в окошке самой Idea:

> tools.jar seems to be not in Idea classpath. Please ensure Java_HOME points to JDK rather  than JRE.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, вы установили лишь JRE, но не установили при этом JDK.

Вы можете сделать это, например, следующим образом (для установки Java 7 JDK):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```